# Aligning Y-Axis Labels with Bar Charts using PGFPlots

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I have been struggling with the following piece of code for a little while now, and I am about to give up! Hopefully someone can assist so I can show multiple bar charts in one figure.

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                width=0.8\textwidth,
                reverse legend,
                height=18cm,
                xbar,
                xmin=0, xmax=35,
                ytick={1,2,3},
                yticklabels={EE1, EE2, EE3},
                nodes near coords,
                nodes near coords align={horizontal},
                legend style={
                    at={(1.1,0.5)},
                    anchor=west,
                    draw,
                    fill=none,
                    legend columns=1,
                    /tikz/column 2/.style={column sep=10pt},  % Adjust the spacing between legend entries
                },
            ]
            \addplot [fill=blue] coordinates {(6, 1)};
            \addplot [fill=green] coordinates {(16, 1)};
            \addplot [fill=yellow] coordinates {(14, 1)};
            \addplot [fill=orange] coordinates {(8, 1)};
            \addplot [fill=red] coordinates {(8, 1)};
            
            \addplot [fill=blue] coordinates {(6, 2)};
            \addplot [fill=green] coordinates {(16, 2)};
            \addplot [fill=yellow] coordinates {(14, 2)};
            \addplot [fill=orange] coordinates {(8, 2)};
            \addplot [fill=red] coordinates {(8, 2)};
            
            \addplot [fill=blue] coordinates {(6, 3)};
            \addplot [fill=green] coordinates {(16, 3)};
            \addplot [fill=yellow] coordinates {(14, 3)};
            \addplot [fill=orange] coordinates {(8, 3)};
            \addplot [fill=red] coordinates {(8, 3)};
            
            % Specify the legend entries and their colors
            \addlegendimage{fill=blue}
            \addlegendentry{Strongly Agree}
            
            \addlegendimage{fill=green}
            \addlegendentry{Somewhat Agree}
            
            \addlegendimage{fill=yellow}
            \addlegendentry{Neutral}
            
            \addlegendimage{fill=orange}
            \addlegendentry{Somewhat Disagree}
            
            \addlegendimage{fill=red}
            \addlegendentry{Strongly Disagree}
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{adjustbox}
    \caption{Results of ...}
    \label{bc:EE1}
\end{figure}
```

This code gives me the following image:

[image: BarChart]

However, as you can see: EE2 aligns perfectly in the middle of those bars, but for EE3 and EE1 this is not the case. How can I fix this? I have a bunch of bar charts I need to discuss so forcing a few into one figure would clean up my PDF a bit, at least I thought.